# Set different heights per screen size with inline styles CSS into the 'Text' section of a Page

Tags: pages, css, html

I embedded a 360 Virtual Tour on a Wordpress page using the following code:

```html
<div align="center">
<div style="width: 75%; height: 75%;">
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 50.00%; padding-top: 35px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="html-websiteaddress" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything works pretty well but I need to be able different heights per screen size.
Exemple: 
laptop/desktop screen --> `<div style="width: 75%; height: 75%;">`
mobile device screen  --> `<div style="width: 100%; height: 75%;">`

I've been told it's possible to do so by using inline styles CSS, so far I cannot find how to. I found about media queries but this seems to be plain CSS element.
Anyone can help? I've been looking for 5 hours aleady and I'm getting desperate :/

Comment: It’s not possible with inline styles only. Whoever told you that is misinformed.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Media Queries**. Give that element a **class** & style it through media query following different screen sizes.

Here is the sample:

**HTML**

```
<div align="center">
<div class="resolution">
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 50.00%; padding-top: 35px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="html-websiteaddress" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

**For bigger screens (laptop/desktop) use different widths like:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { <-- /* Whatever screen size you want to put here */
.resolution {
width: 75%;
height: 75%;
}
}
```

**For smaller screens (mobile/tab) use different widths like:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { <-- /* Whatever screen size you want to put here */
.resolution {
width: 100%;
height: 75%;
}
}
```

To understand Media Queries better Here are few references : [Web Design Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)  & [Media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for taking time to write the code. It work perfectly and I learnt that it is finally not difficult to add CSS into the custom.css file :)

Comment: Glad it helped, Please accept this answer if it worked for you :)